# How to render this horizontally?

Tags: vue.js, alignment, vuetify.js, horizontallist

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="i in 9">
      <div v-if="i != 2 && i != 3 && i != 7 && i != 8 && i != 9" :key="i">
        <v-chip>
          {{ i }}
        </v-chip>
      </div>
      <v-chip :key="i" v-else>
        {{ i }}
      </v-chip>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

This snippet generates this output

[image]

How to render exactly this output but horizontally to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVe3a.jpg)

Comment: I did not understand the logic ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal https://imgur.com/a/tDwjObF

Comment: Your snippet not generating the output which you shown in the image.

Comment: Can you please share the `fiddle` or `codepen` link ? to understand it in more better way.

Comment: This generates the list vertically and chips 2,3 and 7,8,9 are on the same row. I want this horizontally with the chips 2,3 and 7,8,9 in the same column like in the image.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-sea-qg3coq?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you consider using an array from `data` option, this might work

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="(i, index) in items">
      <div v-if="!isNaN(i)" :key="index">
        <v-chip>
          {{ i }}
        </v-chip>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline" v-else :key="index">
        <v-chip v-for="(n, index) in i" :key="index">
          {{ n }}
        </v-chip>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [1, [2, 3], 4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chip group component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chip-groups/)

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    sizes: [
      '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
    ],
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-chip-group
          v-model="selection"
        >
          <v-chip
            v-for="size in sizes"
            :key="size"
            :value="size"
          >
            {{ size }}
          </v-chip>
        </v-chip-group>
      
  </v-app>
</div>
```